# Excel macro execution crushing, trying to simplify the formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I am quite new to excel-Macros, therefore I don't find the reason why the following macro is crushing my excel (both on mac and win). Therefore, I would like to try to simplify the formula, reducing the many if's to a single formula. Could you please help?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("B8")

If Range("B8").Value = "0" Then
    Rows("14:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("13").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("B14:B24").Clear
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = "Open"
End If

If Range("B8").Value = "1" Then
    Rows("15:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("13:14").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = "Open"
    Range("B15:B24").Clear
End If

If Range("B8").Value = "2" Then
    Rows("16:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("13:15").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = "Open"
    Range("B16:B24").Clear
End If

If Range("B8").Value = "3" Then
    Rows("17:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("13:16").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = "Open"
    Range("B17:B24").Clear
End If

If Range("B8").Value = "4" Then
    Rows("18:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("13:17").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("B18:B24").Clear
End If

If Range("B8").Value = "5" Then
    Rows("19:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("13:18").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("B19:B24").Clear
End If

If Range("B8").Value = "6" Then
    Rows("20:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("13:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("B20:B24").Clear
End If

If Range("B8").Value = "7" Then
    Rows("21:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("13:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("B21:B24").Clear
End If

If Range("B8").Value = "8" Then
    Rows("22:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("13:21").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("B22:B24").Clear
End If

If Range("B8").Value = "9" Then
    Rows("23:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("13:22").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("B23:B24").Clear
End If

If Range("B8").Value = "10" Then
    Rows("24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("13:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("B24").Clear
End If

If Range("B8").Value = "11" Then
    Rows("13:24").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```

As you can see, the logic of the formulas is: The higher the value of B8, the less rows between 13 and 24 are hidden. The smaller the value of B8, the more hidden rows AND clearing of the values of hidden rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first, set the entire set of rows 13-34 to be visible (`.Hidden = False`), and later according to the value in `Range("B8").Value` set how many rows you want to hide.

I also think you want to run this code only when a value in Range("B8") has changed, so you can add a line in your `Worksheet_Change` event to check : `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B8")) Is Nothing Then`.

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = True
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B8")) Is Nothing Then ' <-- run this code only when changing the value of B8
    Select Case Target.Value

        Case 0 To 11
            Range("B13:B24").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("B" & 14 + Target.Value & ":B24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("B" & 14 + Target.Value & ":B24").Clear
        Case Else
            'do nothing

    End Select
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @Michael  you're welcome, please mark as answer by clicking the little **V** next to my answer

Comment: for the same project, does it happen that you are able to give me a solution for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810456/search-which-cell-contains-a-specific-text-and-modify-an-offset-cell   תודה רבה לך in advance!

Comment: it's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve there, can you add a screen-shot to your post, what is the current situation and what is the desired rersult

Answer (score 0):

It's slow because every time your code changes the worksheet, the change event is called again. So you're in a position where you've got many change events running recursively.

To see what was originally happening in your code, you can 'step through' the sequence using F8. You'll see when the marker reaches the Clear statement, the Worksheet_Change event is called again

You can stop this by keeping track of when the original change event has finished with a variable declared outside of the Subroutine, as shown below:

```
Public booCancelChange As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("B8")

'Test whether to run
If Not booCancelChange Then
    'Stop recursive calls
    booCancelChange = True

    If Range("B8").Value = "0" Then
        Rows("14:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("13").EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Range("B14:B24").Clear
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = "Open"
    End If

    If Range("B8").Value = "1" Then
        Rows("15:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("13:14").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = "Open"
       Range("B15:B24").Clear
    End If

    If Range("B8").Value = "2" Then
        Rows("16:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("13:15").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = "Open"
       Range("B16:B24").Clear
    End If

    If Range("B8").Value = "3" Then
        Rows("17:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("13:16").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = "Open"
       Range("B17:B24").Clear
    End If

    If Range("B8").Value = "4" Then
        Rows("18:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("13:17").EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Range("B18:B24").Clear
    End If

    If Range("B8").Value = "5" Then
        Rows("19:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("13:18").EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Range("B19:B24").Clear
    End If

    If Range("B8").Value = "6" Then
        Rows("20:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("13:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Range("B20:B24").Clear
    End If

    If Range("B8").Value = "7" Then
        Rows("21:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("13:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Range("B21:B24").Clear
    End If

    If Range("B8").Value = "8" Then
        Rows("22:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("13:21").EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Range("B22:B24").Clear
    End If

    If Range("B8").Value = "9" Then
        Rows("23:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("13:22").EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Range("B23:B24").Clear
    End If

    If Range("B8").Value = "10" Then
        Rows("24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("13:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Range("B24").Clear
    End If

    If Range("B8").Value = "11" Then
        Rows("13:24").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

    'Now that the original change event has completed, allow future change evnets
    booCancelChange = False
End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are autocalculation is slowing you down. It's always a good idea to turn it off in slow functions.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

....

    Application.Calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```